# Calculating $\nabla\bigg[ (z_i - c)^{T} \mathbf{A} (z_i - c) - 1 \bigg]$ using matrix calculus

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-calculus

I'm trying to calculate $\nabla\bigg[ (z_i - c)^{T} \mathbf{A} (z_i - c) - 1 \bigg]$ with respect to the following variables; matrix $\mathbf{A}$ and the $c$ vector.
I tried calculating it and ended up with getting $$\frac{\partial}{\partial c}\bigg[ (z_i - c)^{T} \mathbf{A} (z_i - c) - 1 \bigg] = -2 \mathbf{A} (z_i - c)$$
and 
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\bigg[ (z_i - c)^{T} \mathbf{A} (z_i - c) - 1 \bigg] = (z_i - c)^{T} \frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{A}} (z_i - c)$$ where I assume $\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial \mathbf{A}}$ is a matrix of ones with the same dimensions and $\mathbf{A}$.

The problem now occurs when I want to optimize this with steepest descent and backwards line search using `numpy`. For some reason I am getting a scalar from $\frac{\partial}{\partial \mathbf{A}}\bigg[ (z_i - c)^{T} \mathbf{A} (z_i - c) - 1 \bigg]$ but I am not quite sure how I am supposed to apply this to my problem, as every matrix element of $\nabla \mathbf{A}$ now is equal. I'm just wondering if I have some of the matrix calculus wrong here? 
Or if this is a programming mistake. I'm currently using `np.dot(x, np.dot(A_diff, x))`

I've tested the optimization algorithm and it works for $c$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your derivative calculation. It actually holds that

$$
\nabla_{A} \left[ (z_i - c)^\top A (z_i - c) - 1 \right] = (z_i - c) (z_i - c)^\top,
$$

which has the same dimensions as $A$. In NumPy this is just `np.outer(z - c, z - c)`, assuming that `z, c` are the vectors $z_i, c$ respectively.

**Edit**: To see why this is true, the most straightforward way is to write

$$
x^\top A x = \mathrm{tr}(x^\top A x) = \mathrm{tr}(xx^\top A) = \langle xx^\top, A \rangle \Rightarrow
\frac{\partial x^\top A x}{\partial A} = xx^\top,
$$
where the above steps use the cyclic invariance of the trace and the fact that
$ \mathrm{tr}(A^\top B) = \langle A, B \rangle$, the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. You can also verify the above expression [here](http://www.matrixcalculus.org/), or check against the table in the relevant [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix_identities).

Yet another way to verify the above is to write the quadratic form above as

$$
x^\top A x = \sum_{i=1, j=1}^n x_{i} x_j A_{ij} \Rightarrow
\frac{\partial x^\top A x}{\partial A_{ij}} = x_i x_j,
$$

so when you actually put this together in a matrix it gives you precisely the outer product $x x^\top$, since $(xx^\top)_{i,j} = x_i x_j$

Comment: Could you provide some more information about where I have the error in my derivative calculation? I've tried `np.outer`, but still dont get the proper optimization results.

Comment: @GjertG: no problem, see edit above.